# What is meant by the so often heard phrase that we only use 12% of the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

I have heard it so often that we use only 12% of our brain. I truly don't understand this. All neurons in the brain are are firing within a small amount of time. Even in my sleep this is going on.

What is meant by 12%?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpretation & Actual Result of “10% of your brain” Myth](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/12281/7001)

Comment: That's just a myth and is not scientifically proven. As you mentioned, the brain is working even during sleep, and you cannot say that only x% is working, because the brain uses the capacity it has. The capacities can be improved - but then it will still be using what it has (=full capacity).